# Evaluate equation for multiple values

Tags: replacement, syntax

This works fine;

```
((x - Sqrt[x])/(x + Sqrt[x]) - (x^2 - x)/36) /. x -> {1, 4, 8}
```

but this does not

```
((x - Sqrt[x])/(x + Sqrt[x]) == (x^2 - x)/36) /. x -> {1, 4, 8}
```

I expected it to return `{True, True, False}` but it returns a single `False`.

How do I get `{True, True, False}`? TIA.

Comment: for fun: `MapThread[Equal, {(x - Sqrt[x])/(x + Sqrt[x]), (x^2 - x)/36} /. x -> {1, 4, 8}]` or `{(x - Sqrt[x])/(x + Sqrt[x]), (x^2 - x)/36} /. x -> {1, 4, 8} // MapThread[Equal]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps `Map` is what you are looking for

```
Map[(((x - Sqrt[x])/(x + Sqrt[x]) == (x^2 - x)/36)) /. x -> # &, {1,4, 8}]
(*{True, True, False}*)
```

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
((# - Sqrt[#])/(# + Sqrt[#]) == (#^2 - #)/36) & /@ {1, 4, 8}
{True, True, False}
```

or

```
(x |-> ((x - Sqrt[x])/(x + Sqrt[x]) == (x^2 - x)/36)) /@ {1, 4, 8}
{True, True, False}
```

( |-> is Function, version 12.3!)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `ReplaceAll`, you just have to tell it to do multiple replacements for the different values of `x`:

```
((x - Sqrt[x])/(x + Sqrt[x]) == (x^2 - x)/36) /. 
  {{x -> 1}, {x -> 4}, {x -> 8}}
(* {True, False, True} *)
```